# How to delete an element in a ListView when I'm using collections?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I need to delete a selected element in a ListView using a delete button. The ListView is being filled using data collections and a web service to bring the data from a database. I'm also using MVVM.

This is the click event for the button:

```
private void Click_Button_Delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Collection3VM.DinamicSummary.Remove(Collection3VM.DinamicSummary.---);
}
```

Where Collection3VM is the resource reference for the ViewModel named in the xaml code, and DinamicSummary is the property created in the ViewModel. What command or should I use where the --- are?

Comment: this is not MVVM as Sniffer says below, you need to change your approach

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing it the right MVVM way. You can declare a property in your view model with a type equal to type of the collection items, then in your xaml and inside the ListBox element you can do something like this:

```
SelectedItem = {Binding Path=TheNameOfThePropertyYouChoseInYourViewModel,
Mode=OneWayToSource}
```

and then associate the delete button with a Command on the same view model and the button is clicked then you can do something like this in your view model:

```
var selectedItem = TheNameOfThePropertyYouChoseInYourViewModel; 
yourCollection.Remove(selectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

*DinamicSummary* should be of type ObservableCollection.